# Large Logo box in Navbar without expanding the navbar height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Im trying to center a logo in Bootstrap 5 navbar. Im able to achieve it with a css order:# definition, but I need my logo to take up more space than I have in the navbar. Navbar height is 80px, and I need logo box to take up 140px in height. Whenever I add min-height, or padding or anything like that to the logo box, to increase in height, it also increases the navbar height.

Im trying to achieve something that  St Marys university website does, for example. You can see it here: https://www.stmarytx.edu/  Logo is centered and is outside of the navbar panel and even though logo has a bigger height than the parent container panel, the parent container panel still has the 49px height.

Can anyone explain to me please how they achieved this without using the absolute positioning?
Ive searched for a lot of flexbox tutorials but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: it is a li, child of ul.menu... if you comment `order:4`, you'll see that is a normal child...

Answer (score 0):

That site has given the menu a fixed height.

Overflow is not set to hidden so a larger child will show.

Here's a simplistic example of a menu with the 'logo' element as the 4th item:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

ul.menu>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul.menu>li.logo {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: darkblue;
  margin-top: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="logo">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```